# How to perform lots of matrix multiplications efficiently

Tags: matlab

I have a Matlab table with several variables. Each cell in column `T` contains a `3-by-3` matrix. And each row of column `A` contains a `1-by-3` matrix. (As in [this file](https://www.dropbox.com/s/i8s874qrg8gwe2e/matlab.mat?dl=0).)
[image: Table structure]

I would like to create a new column `C` in the table by multiplying every matrix in `A` with the corresponding matrix in `T`, to get `C(i,:) = A(i,:)*T{i}`. How can I do this efficiently?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Approach #1: `for`

```
K.C = zeros(size(K.A));
for ii = 1:size(K.A,1)
    K.C(ii,:) = K.A(ii,:)*K.T{ii};
end
```

### Approach #2: `rowfun`

```
K.C = cell2mat(rowfun(@(T,A) A*T{1},K,'InputVariables',{'T','A'},'Outputformat','cell'));
```

### Approach #3: `parfor`

```
C = zeros(size(K.A)); 
A = K.A; 
T = K.T;
parfor ii = 1:size(K.A,1)
    C(ii,:) = A(ii,:)*T{ii};
end
K.C = C;
```

### Approach #4: `cellfun`

```
K.C = cell2mat(cellfun(@mtimes, num2cell(K.A, 2), K.T, 'UniformOutput', false));
```

### Speed Comparison:

The `cellfun` approach wins by a factor of 100 compared to the `for`-loop on my machine.

[image: Speed comparison]

Comment: Thanks, it works well. However, as it relies on the cellfun approach, the speed is relative slow. I'll keep looking into this.

Comment: @Naiqi: I improved on the `cellfun` version. I don't think you will find anything faster than `cellfun`. A factor of 100 compared to the naive `for` loop isn't that bad!

Comment: Yes, it's indeed much faster. The reason I asked so much for the speed is that the dataset I'm working on has million rows to deal with. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Actually, I did some modifications on your code by converting the table into cell. Now it is 100X faster!!! Super!

Comment: What did you end up using?